# How to show upcoming events according to start date field

Tags: php

I am trying to show upcoming events. I have created a custom post type "event" in wordpress. and by using ACF plugin i have created date field for every event. now i want to show upcoming events. Here is my code. it is not working

```
$today = date('D. j. M');
$customEvent = new Wp_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_value' => date('D. j. M'),
    'compare' => '>=',
));
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into how the date values are being saved. If you have an option to save them as a Unix timestamp, that will likely give you the best comparison, as it will be a matter of comparing one number to another. It looks like your current code is trying to compare textual representations, which is not an easy comparison and is probably why you're not getting results.

Answer (score 0):

1. check phpmyadmin or similar database tool to see how your `start_date` is being stored.
2. When you find how the variable is being stored, query all events and get their `start_dates`s, convert each one into a date object and compare it to today's date and only display events whose `start_date` is after today.
   (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparing-two-dates-in-php/)